# How do I save inner scope variable to use with outside scope?

Tags: javascript, variables

How do I get the variable `cool` so I can use it outside the function of `gotSpeech()`? I want to use it for the function `guessedCorrect()` which will also run when I click on the button. Is that possible?

```
let speechRec = new p5.SpeechRec('en-US', gotSpeech);

function gotSpeech() {
    if (speechRec.resultValue) {
        cool = speechRec.resultString;
        if (cool == "0") {
            zero.style.color = "#dc3545";
        }
        if (cool == "5") {
            five.style.color = "#dc3545";
        }
        if (cool == "10") {
            ten.style.color = "#dc3545";
        }
        if (cool == "15") {
            fifteen.style.color = "#dc3545";
        }
        if (cool == "20") {
            twenty.style.color = "#dc3545";
        }
    }
}

button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    resetround();
    speechRec.start();
    setTimeout("getComputerChoice()", 3000);
    setTimeout("identifyHands()", 3000);
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    myInterval = setInterval(function() {
        time--;
        if (time == -1) {
            button.innerHTML = "Again";
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            time = 4;
        } else {
            button.innerHTML = "Start";
            numbers.innerHTML = time;
        }
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout("guessedCorrect()", 5000);
})
```

Output returns `undefined` when it's outside of scope.

Comment: Would it be better if you could include/explain where the harcoded methods are being called from? Also, not a good idea to use string names of methods. If you are doing minification of scripts, the methods name that you haev in string literals, would be changed at runtime to something like a(), b().. to save space and you would never find a method named "getComputerChoice" etc,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number of ways to go about this. The most obvious is to modify your call to `guessedCorrect()` to explictly pass it:

```
setTimeout(() => { guessedCorrect(cool); }, 5000);
```

Of course this will mean you'll need to modify the definition of `guessedCorrect()` to accommodate the incoming argument, i.e.:

```
function guessedCorrect(cool) { //...
```

This has the bonus advantage of not referring to the function by string name. As @Shahzad says, this would result in your code breaking on minification since minification doesn't change strings. Better is to use function references, so:

```
setTimeout(guessedCorrect, 5000);
```

Also, your repetitious `if/else if` blog can be greatly reduced by using a `switch()` block or even an object as a value-to-colours map.

[EDIT]

In response to your later comment:

`this` is the context in which the current closure is being executed. The default context, i.e. until something changes it, is `window`. Often context is set automatically, e.g. in event callbacks where `this` points to the triggering element. But in your case we could (though it would be a rather strange approach) contrive `this` to point to the value of `cool`, so:

```
setTimeout(guessedCorrect.bind(cool), 5000);
```

After that, calling `this` inside `guessedCorrect()` will bring up the value of `cool` that existed when the function was called.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about minification @Shahzad and @Utkanos. However I just changed the code to     `setTimeout(() => { guessedCorrect(cool); }, 5000);` and I'm getting this error on the line: `Uncaught ReferenceError: cool is not defined` . My `cool` variable is only within the gotSpeech function. So I'm still confused....

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me. You mentioned there are other ways, if you have time could you explain a bit more? I tried to use `this.` but I couldn't really understand it.

Comment: "*this is the context in which the current closure is being executed*" is not correct. *this* is a **property** of an execution context (strictly, an environment record), it is not the context itself (to which you can't get a reference). For an arrow function, *this* belongs to an outer execution context. In strict mode, it may not be set at all.

Comment: @noontimexpress—see [*MDN: this*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you actually need the value and not the variable; and the value you already have access to it using the `speechRec.resultString` dot notation.

You could try something like this:

```js
// An modification that the post from above offers you, which is pretty good for this case. value-to-colours 
const colors = {
 0: '#dc3545',
 5: '#dc3545',
 10: '#dc3545',
 15: '#dc3545',
 20: '#dc3545',
};

function gotSpeech() {
    if (speechRec.resultValue) {
        zero.style.color = colors[speechRec.resultString];
    }
}

button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    resetround();
    speechRec.start();
    // Why are you passing the functions as string?
    // Better do this

    setTimeout(getComputerChoice, 3000);
    setTimeout(identifyHands, 3000);
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    myInterval = setInterval(function() {
        time--;
        if (time == -1) {
            button.innerHTML = "Again";
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            time = 4;
        } else {
            button.innerHTML = "Start";
            numbers.innerHTML = time;
        }
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(guessedCorrect.bind(null, speechRec.resultString), 5000);
})
```

If you have your `guessedCorrect` function exported from another file, I would use the `bind` function to create a new function with the given params. Otherwise, if you have the function in the same file, just pass the function like this:

```js
setTimeout(guessedCorrect, 5000);
```

and within the function just use the global variable `speechRec.resultString`.

> Note: Try to use strict comparison (`===`) instead of the abstract (`==`).